# how to remove sorting icon in grouped column tag in kendo data-grid angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am using angular 14 with kendo UI data grid (version 7.2.4) for displaying data.
By default the kendo grid allows events like filtering, sorting, grouping, and so on.

I have enabled sorting for the required columns, and I have also enabled grouping based on the column name. When I apply grouping, (usually through a drag & drop action on the column header), the name of the column which I have grouped appears at the top with a close icon referring to remove grouping on that column.

I have added the image below of how it would look if I apply grouping below:

[What it looks like after grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLI2J.png)

But what I actually want to achieve is I want the sort icon (up arrow icon) in the (**Element name** tag in the grid with a close icon) to be removed.

I've searched for options to remove this icon from the grouped column name tag template, But I've found nothing useful so far...

Comment: I have this problem as well. Have you found any way to accomplish this?

Comment: No @DanielG , the requirements have changed and grouping was not required anymore
and so I have not looked into it after